# WIX remove previous version and install new version

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I'am using WIX and losing my hair very quickly!

So I have my application installed on my pc - the version number is 1.1.1.0. I wish to install my new version (1.1.2.0) AND remove the previous version at the same time. I have gone through a few tutorials and have basically been trying trail and error to get this to work but cannot.

Below is my code I can't see what exactly I am missing though?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <?define ProductName="Order Entry"?>
  <?define ProductCode="4e447072-689e-4641-ad60-8ae18f1bfcf0"?>
  <?define UpgradeCode="27cb76c7-544e-465f-b1f3-b11d9a49e416"?>
  <?define RTMProductVersion=1.1.1.0?>
  <?define ProductVersion=1.1.2.0?>

  <Product Id="$(var.ProductCode)"  
       Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"            
       Name="$(var.ProductName)" 
       Language="1033" 
       Manufacturer="MyCompany" 
       UpgradeCode="4e447072-689e-4641-ad60-8ae18f1bfcf0">

 <Package InstallerVersion="300" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine"  />
 <Media Id="1" Cabinet="myCab.cab" EmbedCab="yes" CompressionLevel="medium" />

<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)"
                  IncludeMinimum="no"
                  OnlyDetect="yes"      
                  Language="1033" 
                  Property="NEWPRODUCTFOUND"/>

  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.RTMProductVersion)"
                  IncludeMinimum="yes"
                  Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)"
                  IncludeMaximum="no"
                  Language="1033" 
                  Property="UPGRADEFOUND"/>
</Upgrade>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize"/>
  <!-- <InstallExecute After="RemoveExistingProducts" />-->
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: possible duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269438/how-to-get-wix-major-upgrade-working

Comment: The general case is documented [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html).